# React firebase auth() setState not working inside then()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have this twitter sign in from firebase document and I wanted to save `uid` state but it doesn't work. Any idea whats going on here?

```
twitterSignin(provider) {

    var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
    var getStoreID = this.props.storeId;

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(function (result) {
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            var user = result.user;

            var ref = firebase.database().ref(getStoreID);

            ref.once("value")
                .then(function (snapshot) {
                    var data = snapshot.val();

                    if (!data.owner) {
                        ref.set({
                            owner: result.user.uid
                        })
                    }

                    this.setState({
                        uid: result.user.uid
                    })

                });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.code)
            console.log(error.message)
        });
}
```

Thanks

Fixed:

```
    twitterSignin(provider) {

        var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
        var getStoreID = this.props.storeId;
var that = this;

        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then(function (result) {
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                var user = result.user;

                var ref = firebase.database().ref(getStoreID);

                ref.once("value")
                    .then(function (snapshot) {
                        var data = snapshot.val();

                        if (!data.owner) {
                            ref.set({
                                owner: result.user.uid
                            })
                        }

                        that.setState({
                            uid: result.user.uid
                        })

                    });
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error.code)
                console.log(error.message)
            });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access `setState` from a different scope. In order to fix the problem, you need to bind the callbacks to the instance. For that you have a couple options, using `bind`, cache the parent scope `const me = this;` and then use `me` inside the callbacks or use an arrow function.

```
twitterSignin(provider) {

  var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
  var getStoreID = this.props.storeId;

  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((result) => {
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      var user = result.user;

      var ref = firebase.database().ref(getStoreID);

      ref.once("value")
        .then((snapshot) => {
          var data = snapshot.val();

          if (!data.owner) {
            ref.set({
             owner: result.user.uid
            })
          }

          this.setState({
            uid: result.user.uid
          })

        });
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.code)
    console.log(error.message)
  });
}
```

I'd go with the arrow function.

---

An arrow function gets executed in the outer scope, in this case the scope of `twitterSignin`, which is your react component, the one with the `setState` :)